# Operator '<' cannot be used with a left hand side of

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, tweak

I have been debugging this for some time but even though I knew what to do, I don't know what kind of code to put

this is the error message that I always recieve

```
Assets/scripts/JavaScripts/PerformanceTweak.js(220,32): BCE0051: Operator '<' cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'Object' and a right hand side of type 'float'.
```

Although I know that i need to convert the object to float, I am having hard time coding for it.
while this is the code I have.

```
var fpsCounter : FPSCounter;
var terrain : Terrain;
var messageTime = 10.0;
var scrollTime = 0.7;

private var messages = new Array();
private var times = new Array();
private var lastTime = 0.0;
private var doneNotes = false;
private var origDetailDist = 0.0;
private var origSplatDist = 0.0;
private var origTreeDist = 0.0;
private var origMaxLOD = 0;
private var softVegetationOff = false;
private var splatmapsOff = false;

private var lowFPS = 15.0;
private var highFPS = 35.0;

private var skipChangesTimeout = 1.0;
private var nextTerrainChange = 0;

function Start()
{
    if( !fpsCounter || !terrain ) {
       Debug.LogWarning("Some of performance objects are not set up");
       enabled = false;
       return;
    }

    origDetailDist = terrain.detailObjectDistance;
    origSplatDist = terrain.basemapDistance;
    origTreeDist = terrain.treeDistance;
    origMaxLOD = terrain.heightmapMaximumLOD;
    skipChangesTimeout = 0.0;

    var distances : float[] = new float[32];
    distances[16] = Camera.main.farClipPlane;
    Camera.main.layerCullDistances = distances;
}

function Update ()
{
    if( !fpsCounter || !terrain )
       return;

    if( !doneNotes && !Application.isEditor )
    {
       var gfxCard = SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceName.ToLower();
       var gfxVendor = SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceVendor.ToLower();
       if( gfxVendor.Contains("intel") )
       {
         // on pre-GMA950, increase fog and reduce far plane by 4x :)
         softVegetationOff = true;
         QualitySettings.softVegetation = false;
         AddMessage( "Note: turning off soft vegetation (Intel video card detected)" );
       }
       else if( gfxVendor == "sis" )
       {
         softVegetationOff = true;
         QualitySettings.softVegetation = false;
         AddMessage( "Note: turning off soft vegetation (SIS video card detected)" );
       }
       else if( gfxCard.Contains("geforce") && (gfxCard.Contains("5200") || gfxCard.Contains("5500") || gfxCard.Contains("6100")) )
       {
         // on slow/old geforce cards, increase fog and reduce far plane by 2x
         ReduceDrawDistance( 2.0, "Note: reducing draw distance (slow GeForce card detected)" );

         softVegetationOff = true;
         QualitySettings.softVegetation = false;
         AddMessage( "Note: turning off soft vegetation (slow GeForce card detected)" );
       }
       else
       {
         // on other old cards, increase fog and reduce far plane by 2x
//       if( hwWater == IslandWater.WaterMode.Simple )
//       {
//          ReduceDrawDistance( 2.0, "Note: reducing draw distance (old video card detected)" );
//       }
       }

       skipChangesTimeout = 0.0;
       doneNotes = true;
    }

    DoTweaks();

    UpdateMessages();
}

function ReduceDrawDistance( factor : float, message : String )
{
    AddMessage( message );
//  RenderSettings.fogDensity *= factor;
//  Camera.main.farClipPlane /= factor;
    var distances : float[] = Camera.main.layerCullDistances;
    for(var i : int = 0; i < distances.Length; i++)
       distances[i] /= factor;
    Camera.main.layerCullDistances = distances;
}

function OnDisable()
{
    QualitySettings.softVegetation = true;
}

function DoTweaks()
{
    if( !fpsCounter.HasFPS() )
       return; // enough time did not pass yet to get decent FPS count

    var fps : float  = fpsCounter.GetFPS();

    // don't do too many adjustments at time... allow one per
    // FPS update interval
    skipChangesTimeout -= Time.deltaTime;
    if( skipChangesTimeout < 0.0 )
       skipChangesTimeout = 0.0;
    if( skipChangesTimeout > 0.0 )
       return;

    // terrain tweaks
    if( fps > 25.0 )
    {
       // bump up!
       ++nextTerrainChange;
       if( nextTerrainChange >= 4 )
         nextTerrainChange = 0;

       if( nextTerrainChange == 0 && terrain.detailObjectDistance < origDetailDist )
       {
         terrain.detailObjectDistance *= 2.0;
         if( !softVegetationOff )
          QualitySettings.softVegetation = true;
         AddMessage( "Framerate ok, increasing vegetation detail" );
         return;
       }
       if( nextTerrainChange == 1 && !splatmapsOff && terrain.basemapDistance < origSplatDist )
       {
         terrain.basemapDistance *= 2.0;
         AddMessage( "Framerate ok, increasing terrain texture detail" );
         return;
       }
       if( nextTerrainChange == 2 && terrain.treeDistance < origTreeDist )
       {
         terrain.treeDistance *= 2.0;
         AddMessage( "Framerate ok, increasing tree draw distance" );
         return;
       }
    }
    if( fps < lowFPS )
    {
       // lower it
       ++nextTerrainChange;
       if( nextTerrainChange >= 4 ) {
         nextTerrainChange = 0;
         lowFPS = 10.0; // ok, this won't be fast...
       }

       if( nextTerrainChange == 0 && terrain.detailObjectDistance >= origDetailDist / 16.0 ) {
         terrain.detailObjectDistance *= 0.5;
         QualitySettings.softVegetation = false;
         AddMessage( "Framerate low, reducing vegetation detail" );
         return;
       }
       if( nextTerrainChange == 1 && !splatmapsOff && terrain.basemapDistance >= origSplatDist / 16.0 )
       {
         terrain.basemapDistance *= 0.5;
         AddMessage( "Framerate low, reducing terrain texture detail" );
         return;
       }
       if( nextTerrainChange == 2 && terrain.treeDistance >= origTreeDist / 16.0 )
       {
         terrain.treeDistance *= 0.5;
         AddMessage( "Framerate low, reducing tree draw distance" );
         return;
       }
    }
    if(fps < 20)
    {
       if(QualitySettings.currentLevel > QualityLevel.Fastest)
         QualitySettings.DecreaseLevel();
    }
    else if(fps > highFPS)
    {
       if(QualitySettings.currentLevel < QualityLevel.Fantastic)
         QualitySettings.IncreaseLevel();
    }

    if(QualitySettings.currentLevel < QualityLevel.Good)
    {
       var sh : Shader = Shader.Find("VertexLit");
       var bumpedObjects : GameObject[] = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Bumped");
       for(var i : int = 0; i < bumpedObjects.length; i++)
       {
         bumpedObjects[i].renderer.material.shader = sh;
       }
    }
}

function AddMessage( t : String )
{
    messages.Add( t );
    times.Add( messageTime );
    lastTime = scrollTime;
    skipChangesTimeout = fpsCounter.updateInterval * 3.0;
}

function UpdateMessages()
{
    var dt = Time.deltaTime;
    for( var t in times )
    parseFloat(t.ToString());  
       parseFloat -= dt;

    var example = times.length;

    var exam = times[0];
    parseFloat(exam.ToString()); 
    while( example > 0 && exam < 0.0 ) {
       times.Shift();
       messages.Shift(); 
    }
    lastTime -= dt;
    if( lastTime < 0.0 )
       lastTime = 0.0;
}

function OnGUI()
{
    var height = 15;
    var n : int = messages.length;
    var rc = Rect( 2, Screen.height - 2 - n * height + (lastTime/scrollTime*height), 600, 20 );
    for( var i = 0; i < n; ++i )
    {
       var text : String = messages[i];
       var time : float = times[i];
       var alpha = time / messageTime;
       if( alpha < 0.2 )
         GUI.color.a = alpha / 0.2;
       else if( alpha > 0.9 )
         GUI.color.a = 1.0 - (alpha-0.9) / (1-0.9);
       else
         GUI.color.a = 1.0;

       GUI.Label( rc, text );
       rc.y += height;
    }
}
```

can you guys please help me?

Comment: In line 219, one line above the error you have: parseFloat(exam.ToString()); Do you want to save the results of that parse somewhere?

Comment: actually even without the parseFloat(exam.ToString()); the same error also occurred. even if i put it outside of the function or anywhere, I still encounter the same error. and I don't think that parseFloat(exam.ToString()); will help me solve the problem. I think I need another code. something that can convert a whole array to float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the bigger gotchas in Unity development: **UnityScript on PC supports dynamic typing, but UnityScript on mobile does not.**

When you declare an `Array()`, everything you push or pop from the array is going to be cast as an `Object`. There's no `<` operator defined to compare `Object` and `float`. With dynamic typing enabled, the script engine will see that your variable is actually a float and proceed comparing it as such; with static typing, you'll have to cast it.

In some circumstances, [UnityScript can infer a variable's type at declaration](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=JavaScript_Type_Inference). In others, you're better off declaring the type yourself.

Google around a bit about Unity and developing with `#pragma strict` to learn more about this.

For now, you should be able to proceed if you give your variable an explicit type:

```
//line 218
var exam : float = times[0];
```